# Customizing Serializers in Django Rest Framework

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am creating an App when I would like the JSON response to be organized when it is received, rather than receiving and organizing.

Currently, I have a ListSerializer type of serializer which would give me response something like

```
[
  {
    "Title": "ABCD",
    "Content": "Article Stuff",
    "Category": "News"
  },
  {
    "Title": "EFGH",
    "Content": "Article Stuff",
    "Category": "Jokes"
  },
  {
    "Title": "QWER",
    "Content": "Article Stuff",
    "Category": "News"
  },

]
```

And I would like it to be something like:-

```
{
  "News": [
    {
      "Title": "ABCD",
      "Content": "Article Stuff",
      "Category": "News"
    },
    {
      "Title": "QWER",
      "Content": "Article Stuff",
      "Category": "News"
    }
  ],
  "Jokes": [
    {
      "Title": "EFGH",
      "Content": "Article Stuff",
      "Category": "Jokes"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have just used the default model serializer till now. I know how I would do this if I created the JSON myself from the SQL result sets, but would be better if I could write a serializer that can do it.
Also, I plan to do a bit of pagination for each category as well after this. But that shouldn't be much of an issue, just would need to put checks where we pull the data from the DB for articles of a particular category, I guess.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Well, there is not much to my code. These are the ponly default viewsets with a category model and an article model.

Answer (score 0):

Override [.to_representation()](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior) method of your serializer.

Since there isn't much information about the ModelClass objects and relationships, here is the example which might help you:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   def to_representation(self, instance):
       response_dict = dict()
       response_dict[instance.section_id] = {
           'News': ArticleSerializer(Article.objects.filter(category="News"), many=True).data,
           'Jokes': ArticleSerializer(Article.objects.filter(category="Jokes"), many=True).data
       }
       return response_dict
```